# Reading CSV file - memory issue

Tags: c, memory, struct

So I had success reading a CSV file like this (The CSV file has 4 columns with x,y,u,v )-

```
while(4 == fscanf(fp, "%f %f %f %f\n", &d.xvalue, &d.yvalue, &d.uvalue, &d.vvalue))
{
    dataset = realloc(dataset, sizeof(*dataset) * (total + 1));
    dataset[total] = d;
    total++;
}
```

The struct -

```
typedef struct {
    double xvalue;
    double yvalue;
    double uvalue;
    double vvalue;
} flow_data;
```

But with a large CSV file, it was performing a realloc over a 100,000 times. I've tried to simplify it to something like this but it's not reading at all now.

```
// Reading flow_data.csv
FILE* fp = fopen(flow_file, "r");

// Checking if the file has been read succesfully
if( fp == NULL)
{
    perror("Error opening file");
    exit(1);
}

char buf[500];
fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), fp); // Skip the first line

int total = 0;
int buf_size = INITIAL_SIZE;
flow_data d;
flow_data* dataset = (flow_data*)malloc(sizeof(flow_data) * buf_size);

while(4 == fscanf(fp, "%lf, %lf, %lf, %lf\n", &d.xvalue, &d.yvalue, &d.uvalue, &d.vvalue))
{
    if (d.xvalue >= 0)
    {
    if (total >= buf_size) {
        buf_size = buf_size * 2;
        dataset = realloc(dataset,buf_size * sizeof(flow_data));
        if (dataset == NULL) {
            printf("error allocating memory!\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }
    dataset[total] = d;
    total++;
    }
}
```

It's only meant to read the line if the X value is larger then 20. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It looks like your `dataset[total] = d` assignment and `d.xvalue >= 20` check are inside your `total + 1 == buf_size` block. You need to adjust your brackets so that the assignment and exit-check happen on every loop, instead of only when you resize the buffer.

Comment: Yep, I've fixed that but still the same issue.

Comment: You can use fseek to skip bytes.

Comment: Would that be instead of fscanf?

Comment: You also need to initialize memory with malloc before realloc, since you don't have INITIAL_SIZE elements' worth of memory initialized. It should work after that (Works on my side)

Comment: Don't grow an array by increments of one, especially when you're dealing with 100k rows.  Keep track of the currently allocated space and the currently used space; double the amount of memory allocated on each reallocation.

Comment: @ShaheAnsar Would that look like - flow_data* dataset = (flow_data*)malloc(sizeof(flow_data) * buf_size);

Comment: @JonathanLeffler are you referring to the total++; part?

Comment: In part — yes.  More to the frequency at which `realloc()` is called (with `dataset = realloc(dataset, sizeof(*dataset) * (total + 1));` in the first fragment)..  The second fragment is more like what it should be, but it isn't entirely clear why you have both the first fragment and the last reasonably significant chunk of code.

Comment: The first fragment is what I previously had, the second fragment is what I've changed it to.

Comment: Please read about creating an MCVE ([MCVE]).  We only need the second example. I should probably remove my comment since your second example more or less does what I suggest. What it doesn't show is `INITIAL_SIZE` — which had better be zero. You also need to be careful not to leak memory: using `some_ptr = realloc(some_ptr, new_size);` is bad because if the `realloc()` fails, `some_ptr` is assigned NULL, which means the previous data is no longer accessible. Use `new_ptr = realloc(old_ptr, new_size); if (new_ptr == NULL) { …out of memory… } old_ptr = new_ptr; old_size = new_size;` or similar.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179288/discussion-between-tobytobias-and-jonathan-leffler).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an implementation of the size-doubling code with the test for `d.xvalue >= 20` condition:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct
{
    double xvalue;
    double yvalue;
    double uvalue;
    double vvalue;
} flow_data;

static void print_dataset(size_t size, flow_data dataset[size]);

int main(void)
{
    char flow_file[] = "flow_data.csv";
    FILE *fp = fopen(flow_file, "r");

    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        perror(flow_file);
        exit(1);
    }

    char buf[500];
    fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), fp); // Skip the first line

    size_t total = 0;
    size_t buf_size = 0;
    flow_data *dataset = NULL;

    flow_data d;
    while (4 == fscanf(fp, "%lf, %lf, %lf, %lf\n", &d.xvalue, &d.yvalue, &d.uvalue, &d.vvalue))
    {
        if (d.xvalue >= 20)
        {
            if (total >= buf_size)
            {
                size_t new_size = buf_size * 2 + 2;
                flow_data *new_data = realloc(dataset, new_size * sizeof(flow_data));
                if (new_data == NULL)
                {
                    printf("error allocating memory!\n");
                    free(dataset);
                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                }
                dataset = new_data;
                buf_size = new_size;
            }
            dataset[total++] = d;
        }
    }

    /* Very unlikely to fail */
    dataset = realloc(dataset, total * sizeof(flow_data));

    print_dataset(total, dataset);

    free(dataset);
    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}

static void print_dataset(size_t size, flow_data dataset[size])
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        printf("[%zu]: (%f, %f) (%f, %f)\n", i,
               dataset[i].xvalue, dataset[i].yvalue,
               dataset[i].uvalue, dataset[i].vvalue);
    }
}
```

Given a sample data file like this (40 lines):

```
22.3,22.3,25.3,24.8
26.5,25.3,21.5,11.5
17.5,12.6,12.8,17.6
17.2,28.5,17.0,23.7
29.6,29.1,28.5,14.2
20.1,15.5,21.5,16.4
26.9,29.0,25.6,13.1
16.7,29.0,26.7,16.4
22.8,14.7,17.4,12.5
27.2,13.8,26.6,25.0
26.7,13.1,26.2,19.3
20.8,25.3,28.8,10.6
27.0,27.0,16.7,10.4
18.4,23.3,16.9,25.9
27.7,17.3,29.2,26.8
14.2,27.6,16.2,10.1
21.7,11.4,21.2,12.6
20.6,12.4,25.5,15.5
29.0,11.4,12.1,18.1
25.7,22.3,24.4,12.9
10.6,22.1,25.6,18.7
25.5,25.1,25.0,29.7
27.3,11.4,16.1,11.3
14.7,11.1,24.0,15.1
29.7,12.1,11.1,22.5
10.5,13.7,22.6,22.6
25.1,16.3,21.2,13.8
17.1,11.5,12.0,24.6
17.5,24.1,19.3,24.8
12.5,29.8,19.7,10.6
11.2,19.6,17.8,24.5
22.4,12.9,10.3,25.8
17.7,10.1,27.9,21.4
18.5,11.7,16.5,24.5
17.0,26.0,20.2,29.6
20.1,11.8,22.3,20.7
25.1,14.1,25.3,13.5
22.6,14.1,26.4,16.2
13.0,29.2,14.7,19.6
17.3,12.6,28.2,15.1
```

it produces the output:

```
[0]: (26.500000, 25.300000) (21.500000, 11.500000)
[1]: (29.600000, 29.100000) (28.500000, 14.200000)
[2]: (20.100000, 15.500000) (21.500000, 16.400000)
[3]: (26.900000, 29.000000) (25.600000, 13.100000)
[4]: (22.800000, 14.700000) (17.400000, 12.500000)
[5]: (27.200000, 13.800000) (26.600000, 25.000000)
[6]: (26.700000, 13.100000) (26.200000, 19.300000)
[7]: (20.800000, 25.300000) (28.800000, 10.600000)
[8]: (27.000000, 27.000000) (16.700000, 10.400000)
[9]: (27.700000, 17.300000) (29.200000, 26.800000)
[10]: (21.700000, 11.400000) (21.200000, 12.600000)
[11]: (20.600000, 12.400000) (25.500000, 15.500000)
[12]: (29.000000, 11.400000) (12.100000, 18.100000)
[13]: (25.700000, 22.300000) (24.400000, 12.900000)
[14]: (25.500000, 25.100000) (25.000000, 29.700000)
[15]: (27.300000, 11.400000) (16.100000, 11.300000)
[16]: (29.700000, 12.100000) (11.100000, 22.500000)
[17]: (25.100000, 16.300000) (21.200000, 13.800000)
[18]: (22.400000, 12.900000) (10.300000, 25.800000)
[19]: (20.100000, 11.800000) (22.300000, 20.700000)
[20]: (25.100000, 14.100000) (25.300000, 13.500000)
[21]: (22.600000, 14.100000) (26.400000, 16.200000)
```

It runs cleanly under [Valgrind](http://www.valgrind.org/) when tested on a Mac running macOS 10.13.6 High Sierra with GCC 8.2.0 and Valgrind 3.14.0.GIT (a version of Valgrind built from a copy of the Git repository rather than a formal release).

```
==76412== HEAP SUMMARY:
==76412==     in use at exit: 23,135 bytes in 168 blocks
==76412==   total heap usage: 195 allocs, 27 frees, 99,487 bytes allocated
==76412== 
==76412== LEAK SUMMARY:
==76412==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==76412==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==76412==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==76412==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==76412==         suppressed: 23,135 bytes in 168 blocks
```

Comment: "Cleanly" is a relative term for the good folks at kde.org. Apparently from `valgrind > 3.12` it no longer provides exclusions for system allocations for `stdio.h` functions for Linux. So as we have discussed before, that "total heap usage:" may not show only the memory you have allocated on "some systems" -- that now seems to apply to "all systems". At least it still gets the *"All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible"* part right on Linux. (no mac to test with so can't verify)

Comment: On a Mac, the system start up code (called before `main()` is called) allocates quite a lot of memory.  The standard I/O system also allocates bits of memory that isn't necessarily cleaned up thoroughly.  I never get 'all heap blocks were freed — no leaks are possible' on a Mac because of these 'still reachable' leaks.  Many of them are suppressed by default (as Valgrind is distributed, or retrieved from Git), but I usually end up adding a number of suppressions.  Currently, I have 15 extra suppressions on macOS 10.13.6 High Sierra with a Valgrind 3.14.0.GIT version.